# Ajax success not rotating on my Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a ajax function. Its passing data to my controller. But i cant get response . I want to rotating page if its success. there is my code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddOrder([FromBody] Order arr)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
            //
            return Json(new { code = 1 });
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

and there is my ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        url: '/Order/AddOrder',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
           if (data == 1)
            {
                location.href = "/Order/Index"; //rotate another controller
            }
    });
```

and im taking this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIh1t.png)

Comment: Hi @BerkayŞimşek, if you have any update,please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[415 Unsupported Media Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)**

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.

As can be seen from your last case, your array may contain files.

Below is a whole demo.

`FileList` class

```
public class FileList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult FileTest()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileTest(FileList model)
    {
        return new JsonResult (new { code = 1 });
    }
```

`FileTest` view:

```
<form id="myform" >
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var Data = new FormData();
            Data.append('code', 'examplecode');
            Data.append('Id', 1);
          
            $("input[type=file]").each(function () {
                var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
                if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                    Data.append("Files", ReadyToUpload[0]);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({  
                url: "/home/FileTest",
                type: 'POST',
                data: Data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 1) {
                            location.href = "/home/Index";
                        }
                    }
                });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Is it because it's [FormBody]?

Comment: No,not like this,

Comment: dont work. when i use this this controller and ajax patameters, i get null value.

Comment: Can you publish your current code? Because it works well for me.

Comment: I solved it in a different way. Ur code helped me. Ty so much :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Hello again. Well, I want to create an event on your return. I mean, if it "succeeds" it should write an alarm. Or I want to return a value from Controller. I tried this with "Get". It didn't work. Values are null. I could not figure it out. Can you help me?